# Azure synapse Merger syntax error for Merge into TSQL

Tags: azure-synapse

Just would like to know what's the problem of the following merge .
[image]

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 5):

As at today, `MERGE` is supported in Azure Synapse Analytics dedicated SQL Pools and in preview.  Simply terminate your statement with a semi-colon, eg

```
MERGE INTO t1 USING t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET t1.col2 = t2.col2
    
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN INSERT ( col1, col2 )
    VALUES ( col1, col2 );
```

Also ensure your target tables are `HASH` distributed in order to avoid the following error:

> Msg 100087, Level 16, State 1, Line 41 Merge statements with a WHEN
> NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET] clause must target a hash distributed table.

See [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/dbc4c435fab1dabfa5fbf90df21127e3) for a full repro script.  See the announcement here for more details:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/new-merge-command-for-azure-synapse-analytics/

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue recently. The MERGE code was correct.
All I did was recreate the Target(destination) table along with Hash distribution on primarykey column.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [SchemaName].[TableName]
( 
    [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [Column1] [nvarchar](50)  NOT NULL,
    [Column2] [datetime2](7)  NOT NULL,
    [Column3] [bit]  NOT NULL
)

WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( [Id] ),  --(hash distributed table on this Id column)
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
```

The Merge code worked.